# Understanding about profile page url on facebook

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Why url for profile page on facebook is like
https://www.facebook.com/username

why not like
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php

Is the the profile page is stored within every username dir ? or something else ?
please clear my doubt and please explain how this type of url for profile is generated ?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Read url rewriting doc: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: @rokas thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

This all about `url rewriting` using `.htaccess` file from the root of the almost all webservers.

The `.htaccess` file can transform `facebook.com/profile.php?p=00012345678` into `facebook.com/00012345678`!

Try to search on Google about `url rewriting`, this can help you alot! :)